# Large difference in pointer address between two pointers

Tags: c, pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  int *p;
  void *q;
  printf("%p\n", p);
  printf("%p\n", q);
}
```

I compiled and ran the above C code, and here's an example output from one run:

```
$ ./a.out
0x10ef55025
0x7ffeeb11f52
```

I immediately noticed that there is a huge gap between the pointer address of the `int` pointer and the `void` pointer, and this behavior is persistent across multiple execution of the code. Is there an explanation for the above explanation?

Comment: `p` and `q` are both uninitialized..  Perhaps you meant `printf("%p\n", &p)`

Answer (score 3):

You never assign a value to `p` or `q`, so printing the values stored within gets your garbage at best. This is what you're seeing.

Note that your compiler should warn you about this if you enable warnings as you should.

```
$ gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic a.c -o a
a.c: In function ‘main’:
a.c:6:12: warning: format ‘%p’ expects argument of type ‘void *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int *’ [-Wformat=]
   printf("%p\n", p);
           ~^
           %ls
a.c:6:3: warning: ‘p’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
   printf("%p\n", p);
   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
a.c:7:3: warning: ‘q’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
   printf("%p\n", q);
   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

If you're trying to print the locations of `p` and `q` themselves (rather than the location of that to which they point), you want

```c
printf("%p\n", (void*)&p);   // Print the address of `p` itself.
printf("%p\n", (void*)&q);   // Print the address of `q` itself.
```

As you saw from the warnings above, `printf`'s `%p` requires a cast to `void*`. It's basically the only time you need to cast to `void*`.

Comment: Aside: "the only time you need to cast to void*" --> likewise for `printf("%p", (void*) NULL);`

Comment: hmm? That's still casting for `%p`. But yeah, it's good to mention because `NULL` can be defined as either `0` or `(void*)0`, so it could require a cast.